# Is there an easy way to get phone's compass heading accuracy in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am building an app for Android and ios with phonegap that includes a compass. Therefore I am using the w3c api as explained [in this article](https://blog.phonegap.com/migrating-from-the-cordova-device-orientation-plugin-8442b869e6cc)

My problem is that the use of the compass is critical in my application so I need to make the user aware that his phone's compass has a problem whenever it is poorly calibrated.

I know for a fact that you can check the compass accuracy with native code in Java for Android. I don't know anything about Swift and ios.

My question is : Would you know any easy way to get the information about the compass accuracy with phonegap ? I've been searching a plugin to do that but I couldn't find anything really (except maybe for Android [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-sensor-listeners) )

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems there were no possible answers to that question. I created the solution :

https://github.com/simsComputing/cordova-plugin-headingcalibration

This is my first cordova plugin so it surely is not perfect. It isn't published on npm yet. 
When I find time to complete it and publish it, i'll do it. In the mean time if anyone finds this thread, feel free to use the plugin.