# How to get heading accuracy of mobile devices?

Tags: mobile-website

I offer a service which needs the correct location and heading of the mobile device the user is accessing my service with. It was relatively easy to get the information but now I am stuck at finding out how accurate the heading I received is.

Since I'm not using any framework for this or develop in Android/iOS, where there are solutions for that problem, I'd need a solution only depending on javascript (+ 3rd party libraries).

I've found the [Generic Sensor API](https://www.w3.org/TR/generic-sensor/) from W3C but couldn't find any sensor which hold that information. Neither the Accelerometer-, nor the AbsoluteOrientationSensor held the needed information.

My current code looks like that..

```
   let accelerometer = null;

    try {
      accelerometer = new Accelerometer({ frequency: 60 });

      accelerometer.addEventListener('error', event => {
        // Handle runtime errors.
        if (event.error.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
          console.log('Permission to access sensor was denied.');
        } else if (event.error.name === 'NotReadableError') {
          console.log('Cannot connect to the sensor.');
        }
      });

      accelerometer.addEventListener('reading', (event) => {
          console.log(accelerometer);
          console.log(event);
      });

      accelerometer.start();
```

.. but since the problem if more of a 'finding the right tool to do the job'-type, it won't help much in better depicting my problems. Further, Google uses kind of the same functionality I'm aiming for in Google Maps, so theoretically there must be a way to get the heading accuracy.

So, in conclusion, is there any way to retrieve the heading accuracy in a simple javascript environment?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I found 1 similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158455/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-phones-compass-heading-accuracy-in-phonegap), but since it only asked specifically about Phonegap I decided to open another question for retrieving the information without any framework in mind.